# Should every injective function be non monotonic?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Is it necessary, that for a function to be injective (one-one) at all points on its domain, it should strictly not be monotonic at any point on its domain?

I reckon that this should be true, because an injective function should have a unique output associated with every input which isn’t valid for monotonic function. Am I correct? Please correct me, wherever wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're confused about something, hard to say what. But if $f(t)=t$ then $f$ is certainly injective and also strictly increasing. (In fact if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and injective then it _is_ montonic...)

Comment: Don't you mean is strictly *should* be monotonic.  Any if it isn't continuous than no.  But If it *is* continuous it must be either monotonical increasing or monotonical decreasing.  A requirement there are unique outputs for every input is that the function can never "backtrack"....

Comment: @BillWallis Not every injective function on $\Bbb R$ is, differentiable, or even continuous.

Comment: Are you assuming without stating it that the function you're speaking about is _continuous_? If not, then it is very easy to find counterexamples.

Comment: @BillWallis: How about $x\mapsto x+\sin x$?

Comment: @BillWallis "if the derivative is zero at more then one point".  What if it is zero and no connected points?  It can't be zero on an interval but if it can certainly have several saddle points.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I seem to have made too broad of a statement --- that is a wonderful counterexample.

Comment: @Aditi: Why on earth do you think that $f(t)=t$ is not monotonic?

Comment: @Henning I do mean continuous functions

Comment: @Aditi: Please _edit the question_ such that it includes that critically important qualification.

Comment: Oh ! I guess I realized my mistake . I now understand it . A strictly increasing function is monotonous but Is also injective

Comment: If it is continuous injective then it *MUST* be monotonic.  But it can't be just non-decreasing or non-increasing.  It must be monotonically *increasing* or *decreasing*.

Comment: @Henning sorry , my bad . I was probably confused between the definition of many one and monotonous functions

Comment: @fleablood yes I’m sorry and thanks ! I was really confused between monotonic and many one functions

Comment: @fleablood but if a function is neither increasing nor decreasing can it still be one one ?

Comment: Are you asking about *continuous* functions, still? (In this case, no: all one-to-one continuous functions are either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.) Or arbitrary functions? (In this case, yes. Almost all bijections $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ will be neither increasing nor decreasing, but they'll also usually not be continuous either.)

Comment: A continuous function that *never* increases or decreases would be a constant function.  They are as monotonous as you can get!  The are monotonicly *non*increasing and monotonically *non* decreasing.  A (continuous) monotonic function doesn't have to be injective.  But a (continuous) injective function must be monotonic.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is continuous (a noncontinuous injective function can jump around all it wants) then an injective function must be either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing (because otherwise it would be "doubling back" on itself--- we can make a calculus proof but ... it is essentially just that intuitive argument; if it's decreasing on some interval but increasing on another it must be going over the same points at least twice.)

However you seem to be confused about what "monotonic" means.  That behavior we just described is *exactly* what monotonic *does* mean and an injective continuous function *must* be monotonic.

(Assuming the function is continuous) then monotonic means the derivative does not change signs.  So the derivative is either always non-negative or alway non-positive.  If the derivative is always $\ge 0$ then the function can never be decreasing so we say it is *monotonically non-decreasing*.  If the derivative is always $\le 0$ then the function can never be increasing so we say it is *monotonically non-increasing*.

I think you confusion comes from these function do allow for intervals in the domain where the function is "flat", has derivative of $0$, is constant.  These monotonic functions can't be injective. To be injective the function must be of a *stronger* type of monotony.

If the function is not allowed to have a $0$ derivative for any measurable integer then it is not merely non-decreasing or non-increasing, it is *actively* increasing or actively decreasing.

If the function is continuous and the derivative is $\ge 0$ and the derivative is never $0$ an a measurable interval of the domain, we conclude the function is *monotonically increasing*.  Notice monotonicaly increasing $\implies $ monotonically non-decreasing.  Monotonically non-decreasing is a weaker condition and monotonically increasing is a stronger one.

Same are conditions if the derivative is $\le 0$ but never on an interval:  That is called *monotonically* decreasing.  And monotonically decreasing $\implies$ monotonically non-increasing.

...

[Note: this are equivalent consequences of the function being continuous and not actual definitions. ]

Comment: Ohhh! Alright I get it now ! Thank you !